# MPI Python input function ,I have a problem with my code

Tags: python, input, process, mpi

I am not able to enter the input after each process. The output I am getting when I execute `mpiexec -n 4 python 1.py`:

```
rank 0 hi
Enter
rank 1 hi
Enter
rank 2 hi
Enter
rank 3 hi
Enter
```

I am able to enter the input only once, that is in the last process, how do I enter input after each rank or process is executed?

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.rank
p=comm.Get_size()


if rank == 0:
    data = "hi
else:
    data = None

data = comm.bcast(data, root=0)

print('rank',rank,data)

x=input("Enter:")
```

Comment: You're missing a quote in ```data = "hi```

Comment: input is generally redirected to rank `0`. you might have a `mpiexec` option to redirect the input to the rank of your choice though.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You cannot send data interactively to the standard input of all MPI ranks. You need to read in one of them, typically in rank 0, and then send the data to the other ranks using MPI communication calls.

Comment: But what if you need different input messages for different MPI ranks.Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you expect `mpiexec` will automagically figure out which MPI task should receive which input?